# Curl request to python

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to make a requests in python. My code is in CURL but I don't know nothing about it and I need the url to make the requests.
I mean for example this could be the url I need:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/sdf/download/ADVERTISER_ID/filterIds/2368848
```

CURL code:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/sdf/download' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"filterIds":[2368848],"filterType":"ADVERTISER_ID"}' \
  --compressed
```

Python code:

```
import httplib2
import json
import csv
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

client_id = r''
client_secret = r''
redirect_uri = ''
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager']
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=client_id,
                           client_secret=client_secret,
                           scope=scope,
                           redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
code = raw_input()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
post = http.request('url', 'POST')
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) ?

Comment: yes, i must use httplib2 @IMCoins